# Bottom pagination is not working while placed at top up the category page in CS Cart?

Tags: pagination, cs-cart

Bottom pagination is not working while placed at top up the category page in  CS Cart!!
Any idea?

Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

go to admin panel settings > appearance > customer settings  check Display the 'Pagination section' on the top of the listed object. hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, However I had fixed that issue that time.